# Window in PyQt5 has size restrictions from last windows

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I had set a fixed size on my Login window however once you login in and it takes you to the LoadingBar window the size restrictions stay even though I set a new fixed size. This leaves my window with blank area. I have tried looking for similar posts but have not found any. This may have a very simple fix and I may have made a very stupid mistake. I would appreciate any help and an explantion. There is no error when running the code

```
#IMPORTS
import sys, os, sqlite3
import random, datetime
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets #, QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QMessageBox
import sqlite3
import time 

#WINDOWS
window1 = uic.loadUiType("login.ui")[0] 
window2 = uic.loadUiType("SIGNUP.ui")[0] 
window3 = uic.loadUiType("main.ui")[0] 
window4 = uic.loadUiType("login_loadingbar.ui")[0]
#CLASSES AND MODULES
class Login(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, window1):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
    
    
    #Set title
    self.setWindowTitle('Login Window')
    self.setFixedWidth(480)
    self.setFixedHeight(620)
        
    self.loginButton.clicked.connect(self.loginfunction)
    self.password_field.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
    self.signupHereButton.clicked.connect(self.gotocreate)

    def loginfunction(self):
        username = self.username_field.text() #ctansley0@imdb.com
        password = self.password_field.text() #ptWYccjTQSKX
    
        if len(username) == 0 or len(password) == 0:
            self.login_text.setText("Please input all fields")
     
        else:
            conn = sqlite3.connect("customersSQL.db")
            cur = conn.cursor()
            query = 'SELECT password FROM customer_data WHERE email = \''+username+"\'"
            cur.execute(query)
            result_pass = cur.fetchone()[0]
            if result_pass == password:
                self.login_text.setText("Successfully logged in")
                

            gotoload = LoadingBar()
            widget.addWidget(gotoload)
            widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
            gotoload.progress()
        else:
            self.login_text.setText("Incorrect username or password")

    def gotocreate(self):
        createacc=CreateAcc()
        widget.addWidget(createacc)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)


class CreateAcc(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, window2):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        #title
        self.setWindowTitle('Signup Window')
        #Push button
        self.signupButton.clicked.connect(self.createaccfunction)
        self.passwordSignup_field.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.confirmPass_field.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        


def createaccfunction(self):
    'This is the create account function where it takes the users input and addes it into the database'
    email = self.usernameSignUp_field.text()
    password = self.confirmPass_field.text()
    if self.passwordSignup_field.text()==self.confirmPass_field.text():
        password=self.passwordSignup_field.text()
        self.signup_text.setText("Successfully created account")
        conn = sqlite3.connect("customersSQL.db")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        #query1 = """INSERT INTO customer_data (email,password)
        #            VALUES(?,?)""", (email,password)
        print (email,password)
   
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO customer_data (email,password)
                    VALUES(?,?)""", (email,password))
        conn.commit()
        time.sleep(3)
        login=Login()
        widget.addWidget(login)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
        
class LoadingBar(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, window4): 
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
            self.setupUi(self)
        
            #title
            self.setWindowTitle('Loading')

        
            self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
       
            self.setFixedHeight(693)
            self.setFixedWidth(351)
        
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
       #makes progress bar go from 0-100, time scaled

        def progress(self):
            for i in range(100):
                time.sleep(0.1)
                self.login_progressBar.setValue(i)
                QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()







class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, window3):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
            self.setupUi(self)
        
        

app=QApplication(sys.argv)
w1=Login()
widget=QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(w1)

widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: What you could try to do is to do `self.setFixedSize(gotoload.maximumSize())`. Unfortunately, the issue is not that simple, and it's mostly caused by the fact that you're following a youtube tutorial that is known to provide an incredible amount of ***terrible*** suggestions. Even assuming that the above solution works, I strongly suggest you to completely ignore that tutorial: we get at least a post a day from people having problems that are *all* caused by it. Ignore it and feel free to down vote it, it's the least it could deserve, and in my opinion it should be completely deleted.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work however I appreciate the advice on how its a terrible tutorial. I will look for other well written solutions, if you know any articles or videos going over login windows on pyqt5 or any other thing about pyqt5 I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Don't look for tutorials on specific subjects; Qt has a peculiar learning curve, it may seem simple (especially if approached with the wrong premises), but it has many important aspects that need considering if you want that level of customization (which is why that tutorial failed under many aspects). Don't rush it, learn step by step. Start with a simple interface, even if it's not good looking: there's always time to improve it. https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Tutorials